# Rotating a cube in 2D space

Tags: c++, matrix, graphics, 3d, 2d

I'm building my own "Graphics Library" which manipulates PPM files under the hood. The library can create videos, too, by utilizing ffmpeg. My library mainly does 2D videos, but I wanted to see if I could create a spinning cube with it. As a warm up, I decided to rotate a square around the X axis (imitating depth). I represent the corners of the square with 4 circles. The issue is, the Y values of the circles seem to slow down the closer they get to the center of the (Here is a [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/4XvfOsiHjhI?feature=share))

This is my code:

```cpp
#include "../src/Mapper/Mapper.hpp" // importing the library
#include <vector>

extern size_t height, width; // importing the height and width of the canvas


const map::Point center{width / 2., height / 2.};

constexpr double square_size = 200.;
constexpr double square_size_half = square_size / 2.;
map::Point points[] = {
     {center.x - square_size_half, center.y - square_size_half} // top left
    ,{center.x + square_size_half, center.y - square_size_half} // top right
    ,{center.x + square_size_half, center.y + square_size_half} // bottom right
    ,{center.x - square_size_half, center.y + square_size_half} // bottom left


std::vector<map::shapes::ShapePtr> spinningCube(const int frame, const int frames, double delta){
    using namespace map;
    using namespace map::shapes;

    const double angle = 180 * delta DEGREES;

    // X rotation matrix
    const double X_MAT[2][2] = {
        {1., 0.},
        {0., cos(angle)}
    };

    std::vector<ShapePtr> shapes;

    for(auto &point : points){
        point.rotate(X_MAT, center);
    }


    for(const auto &point : points){
        shapes.push_back(std::make_unique<Circle>(point, 5, Circle::Data{.color = clr::RED, .filled = false}));
    }

    return shapes;
}


void canvas(map::Mapper &m){
    using namespace map;
    using namespace shapes;


    m.animate(spinningCube, 3);

}
```

As you can tell, the `map::Mapper` class is responsible for everything. Here is the code to the `animate` function:

```cpp
void map::Mapper::animate(std::vector<map::shapes::ShapePtr> (*provider)(const int, const int, const double), float seconds){
    assert(m_FPS > 0 && "FPS must be greater than 0!");
    assert(m_Filename_vid != "" && "Filename must be set before calling animate()!");


    std::clog << "Beginning Scene:\n";
    const int frames = seconds * m_FPS;

    std::vector<map::clr::RGB> temp(m_Map, m_Map + m_Size.width * m_Size.height);
    const size_t temp_size = temp.size() * sizeof(map::clr::RGB);

    for(int frame = 0; frame <= frames; frame++){
        // copy(temp, m_Map); // can be replaced with memcpy
        memcpy(m_Map, &temp[0], temp_size);
        // auto shape = provider(frame, frames, m_Delta);
        auto shape = provider(frame, frames, m_Delta);
        draw(shape, 1);
        if(!m_Set_state) setState();
        saveFrame();
        std::clog << frame << '/' << frames << '\n';

        // delete shape; // for non unique_ptr (old code)
    }
    // copy(temp, m_Map); // can be replaced with memcpy
    memcpy(m_Map, &temp[0], temp_size);

    std::clog << "Scene Ended!\n";
}
```

The `draw` function works well so I don't think the problem is within it so I'm not gonna show its code. Here is part of the `map::Point` class that I'm using in the code up inside the `canvas` function:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <ostream>
#include <concepts>

namespace map{
    struct Point{
        double x{};
        double y{};

        constexpr Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
        constexpr Point(double x_, double y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
        // Point(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
        
        constexpr Point(std::integral auto x_, std::integral auto y_) : x(static_cast<double>(x_)), y(static_cast<double>(y_)) {}


        constexpr friend Point operator * (const double matrix[2][2], const Point& p){
            return {
                p.x * matrix[0][0] + p.y * matrix[0][1],
                p.x * matrix[1][0] + p.y * matrix[1][1]
            };
        }

        constexpr void rotate(double angle, Point center = {0, 0}){
            double ROT_MAT[2][2] = {
                {cos(angle), -sin(angle)},
                {sin(angle), cos(angle)}
            };

            *this -= center;
            *this = ROT_MAT * *this;
            *this += center;
        }

        constexpr Point rotated(double angle, Point center = {0, 0}) const {
            Point p = *this;
            p.rotate(angle, center);
            return p;
        }

        constexpr void rotate(const double ROT_MAT[][2], Point center = {0, 0}){
            *this -= center;
            *this = ROT_MAT * *this;
            *this += center;
        }

        constexpr Point rotated(const double ROT_MAT[][2], Point center = {0, 0}) const {
            Point p = *this;
            p.rotate(ROT_MAT, center);
            return p;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Point& p){
            return os << p.x << ", " << p.y;
        }
    };
}
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed..:). Thanks in advance!

I tried messing up with the rotation function. Changed the matrix multiplication to be a right multiplication instead of left, still didn't work. I have a hunch that the issue is stemming from the fact that I'm completely ignoring the Z value in the point class, but I'm almost certain that there should be a way to do it still. I think it is important to note that the code works well when replacing `X_MAT` with the regular 2D rotation matrix (rotating around the Z axis).

Comment: I hope you mean rotating in 3D, cubes have a tendency not to fit into 2D ;) 
You will still need a 3D rotation matrix even if you rotate around 1 axis

Comment: My attempt was to truncate the 3D rotating matrices to fit into 2D :)).

Comment: You can ofcourse kind of do that... but it will limit your options later. In fact I usually use 4D homogonized coordinats. The idea being that if you want to combine multiple transformations you end up with 1 matrix. And you optimize that process. Also your rotate function will not make it clear what axis it is rotating around so probably is should be `rotate_around_z_axis`

Comment: Your video looks ok to me?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I tried to make the `rotate` function as modular as possible in the sense that it'll just apply the matrix multiplication for whatever matrix you give it. I guess at this point I should just rename it to `matmul` or something of that sort.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it slows down near the center until it reaches a stop right in the center.

Comment: Try looking at your rotation from a different angle/axis

Comment: Intuitively I'd expect the motion to be sinusoidal but I've not written out the maths

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought the same, but the longer I make it run, the more it just stabilizes towards the middle of the canvas until it stops right at the middle and never changes again.

Comment: @PepijnKramer If you mean I should try rotating around different axes, then I tried that. Same result..